# What is wrong with this condition?

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements

i getting errors if one of my conditions is:

```
$conditions[] = array("PublicationNumeration.publication_numerations_published_date" => '2006-01-01' );
```

what is wrong with this condition?

but everything works ok with

```
$conditions[] = array("PublicationNumeration.publication_numerations_published_date" => '2006' );
```

... but that's not all i want/need.

what i'm doing wrong?

**UPDATED:**

next one works ok:

```
$mydate = '2007/01/01';
$conditions[] = array("PublicationNumeration.publication_numerations_published_date LIKE "  =>  date('Y-m-d' , strtotime( $mydate ) ) );
// create sql `PublicationNumeration`.`publication_numerations_published_date` LIKE '2007-01-01'
```

but next one creates an error:

```
$mydate = $this->params['named']['searchPublishedSince'].'/01/01'; // searchPublishedSince is defined in url
$conditions[] = array("PublicationNumeration.publication_numerations_published_date LIKE "  =>  date('Y-m-d' , strtotime( $mydate ) ) );
```

please, what i'm doing wrong?!

Comment: What are the errors? What is the data type of the publication_numerations_published_date field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you follow the scheme:

```
$conditions = array("Post.title" => "This is a post");
//Example usage with a model:
$this->Post->find('first', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

See that it is an array in an array.

Kind regards.

Edit1: BTW you can have a look into the "automagic" of cake e.g. the columns in a database named `created` or `modified` get autoupdated.

Edit2: maybe a `debug($this->params['named']['searchPublishedSince'])` reveals something.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used CakePHP before, but what I gather from the documentation is that those date strings should probably be actual dates. What is the condition you actually want? Do you want a filter that returns publications on Jan 01, 2006, or all greater than Jan 01, 2006?

For publications ON Jan 01, 2006, perhaps try:

```
$conditions[] = array("PublicationNumeration.publication_numerations_published_date" => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2006-01-01')));
```

For all publications >= to Jan 01, 2006, try:

```
$conditions[] = array("PublicationNumeration.publication_numerations_published_date >=" => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2006-01-01')));
```

Comment: `date()` returns a string, so `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2006-01-01'))` is the same as `'2006-01-01'`.

Comment: Ahh, yeah. Sorry, it's been a long time since my PHP days :)